# Почему заглушается вокал если частично извлечь 1/8" аудио разъем?

Tags: аудио, железо, электроника

Каждый раз, когда 1/8" аудио разъем частично извлекается из гнезда, кажется, что приглушается вокал, как будто бы слушаю караоке версию. Насколько понимаю устройство разъема, это невозможно, тем не менее не только я один заметил такой эффект.

Что вызывает приглушение вокала при частично извлеченном аудио разъеме?

Comment: Возможно у вас в разьеме предусмотрен проводок на запись звука(или гарнитуру) а вы пихаете его в разьем где возможно лишь аудио поток. Из моего опыта, гарнитура андроидская(аудио поток, запись поток), подключаем в разьем только для аудио, получаем новое звучание:) без голоса!!! Даже без обработки, решается очень просто, вытащить немножно из разьема. Или иной штекер где предусмотрен лишь аудио поток.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров да, но интересно за счет чего такой эффект

Comment: Не знаю, но вы понимаете что смесь из аудио потока и неизвестно чего(не знаю точно как поток записи на это реагирует) влечет за сабой не предсказуемые последствия.

Comment: http://soundforlife.ru/problemy-s-fazoj/ скорее всего просто вокал идет в моно, все остальное - в стерео

Comment: Вопрос не относится к программному обеспечению и согласно [справке](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), должен быть закрыт как "не по теме".

Comment: @alexolut это так, в порядке эксперимента. Есть же вопросы про фотошоп например. Но в целом да, пока нет профильных сайтов на русском, придется в инглиш писать.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Когда разъем начинает выходить из гнезда, чаще всего его "общий" (земляной) контакт отключается первым. Оставшиеся два контакта (левый и правый каналы) пока остаются подключенными:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В этой ситуации оба наушника продолжают получать сигнал, но теперь это разница между левым и правым каналом. Любой сигнал, имеющий одинаковую фазу в обоих каналах начинает заглушаться.

Звукорежиссеры, как правило, размещают вокал в середине стереопанорамы (в оба канала поступает идентичный сигнал), соответственно разница между каналами для вокала получается нулевой, что и вызывает эффект приглушения вокала.

Answer (score 5):

Любопытный вопрос.

> Небольшой дисклеймер. Весь институтский курс по Теории
>   автоматического регулирования у меня за прошедшие годы вылетел из
>   головы за ненадобностью, поэтому не поручусь
>   за правильность логических построений, а конкретного ответа тем более
>   не дам.

К комментарию про "запись вокала в моно". Обычно вокал и гитара пишется всегда в моно (посмотрите на внешние звуковые карты - они же не имеют стереовыхода для гитары и вокала: там LINE и MIC), но когда доходит до аудиоредактора (кубейз, аудишн) там всегда один из шагов будет приведение сигнала к стерео, что-то типа stereo FX. Так что дело вероятно всё же не в этом.

Я бы поставил на то, что меняется ЛАЧХ/ЛФЧХ системы и сильно режется средний диапазон частот - там где как раз расположен основной диапазон голоса. ЕМНИП, в (аналоговых и ранних цифровых) телефонах ширина одной телефонной линии всего лишь около 300 Гц (обычно у наушников 20 Гц - 20 кГц), так что сильно приглушив как эквалайзером средние частоты будет как раз казаться, что именно вокал стал глуше и тише.

Конкретную механику затрудняюсь описать. Возможно, появляется небольшой воздушный зазор, который действует как добавочное сопротивление/резистор, воткнутое последовательно наушникам. Сопротивление самих наушников небольшое, если у вас не студийные наушники и усилители, там всего лишь с десяток ом, и небольшая мощность самого усилка [в звуковой карте]. При прочих равных при увеличении сопротивления наушников и константной мощности звук будет восприниматься тише, что вы и наблюдаете. Не могу понять, откуда берётся неравномерность изменения для разных частот - по идее, резистор не должен давать таких изменений ЛАЧХ/ЛФЧХ. Рискну предположить, что изменение идёт равномерное: падает громкость во всём частотном диапазоне одинаково (для приборов), но именно "на слух" страдают именно нижние частоты, где находится основной регистр человеческого голоса.

Comment: Вокал и гитара пишутся в моно не потому, что вход один, а потому что это точечные источники. Как и большинство других инструментов. И будет ли там стерео, сильно зависит от жанра, а если и будет - то за счет даблтреков.

Comment: @Etki Выходов обычно два, даже на самой дешёвой звуковухе за 500 рублей, впрочем про точечность источников это не влияет - да и пожалуй это поважнее даже будет, чем стоимость элементной базы, так что тут соглашусь. А что думаете про остальное?

Comment: Что я только что наполовину вытащил штекер своих наушников и слышал явный переворот фазы в одном из каналов. Откуда он там берется - пояснить не берусь.